# How to get azure webapp ip adress to whitelist in storage account

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webapps

I have a azure storage account with firewall setting enabled to allow only specific IP address.
now i have azure web app and web job and from these i am connecting to the storage account to create delete blobs using connection string.but since storage account needs IP address of the web app to access it am not able to do so .
i have tried using inbound and outbound IP address from web app properties those are not working?

Comment: Just put the web app in a virtual network and then allow the VNET to access the storage. By the way, give outbound ip should make it work.

Comment: You can also visit - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security#trusted-microsoft-services

Comment: Any update? Have you trust microsoft service or put the web app in a VNET? Any problems please let me know.